# Is the relative atomic mass directly proportional to the size of an atom?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, atoms, atomic-physics

I have a piece of homework, i have to make a pair of models depicting pure metals and alloys. I want it to be as accurate as possible, and so i'm asking this:

Is the relative atomic mass directly proportional to the size of an atom?

A Hydrogen atom has a relative atomic mass of 1. Lets say that I assign it a Radius of 5cm.

What would the size of a carbon atom be? and Why?

Is there a general formula?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_radius

Comment: Have a look at this graph (http://www.webelements.com/periodicity/atomic_radius/graph.html). As you move along a row in the periodic table the size decreases, but when you move to the next row it jumps up again. So there is no simple formula to relate the size of the atom to its atomic number. To determine the size you would have to do an *ab initio* calculation of the electron configuration, or of course just meaure it.

Comment: I think the close might have been a bit over zealous. The question is actually quite a deep one. Having said that, I'm sure the question is a duplicate because I remember seeing the graph I've linked hereabouts. However a quick search has failed to find the original.